# Existence of point with prescribed value from given differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, integral-equations

I came up with this problem while I was trying to prove the following geometric problem :
Let $A, B$ be the distinct points in $\mathbb{R}^2$. If $r(t)$ is the non self-intersecting trajectory of particle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ starts at $A$ and ends at $B$, is there a moment when velocity vector of particle is pointing same direction with the vector $B-A $ $?$, that is, $r'(t)=c(B-A)$ for some $c>0$$?$
This is definitely not true in general for $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n>2$, but intuitively it must be true for $\mathbb{R}^2$.

First I formalized this problem as follows : Let $r:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ : continuously differentiable unit speed curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $r(a)=(0,0), r(b)=(1,0)$. Then $v(t)=r'(t) \in S^1$.
Now letting $r(t)=(r_1(t),r_2(t))$, $v(t)=(r_1'(t),r_2'(t))$ we get differential equation
$$
r_1'(t)^2 + r_2'(t)^2 = 1
$$
with boundary conditions
$$
r_1(b) = 1\\
r_1(a) = r_2(b) =  r_2(a) = 0
$$

Or equivalently we get integral equations
$$
\int_a^b r_1'(t) dt = r_1(b) -  r_1(a) = 1 \\
\int_a^b r_2'(t) dt = r_2(b) -  r_2(a) = 0 \\
r_1'(t)^2 + r_2'(t)^2 = 1
$$

Lastly we can parametrize $v(t)$ by angle function $\theta(t)$ s.t. $v(t)=(r_1'(t),r_2'(t))=(\cos\theta(t),\sin\theta(t))$ and then we get
$$
\int_a^b \cos\theta(t) dt =  1 \\
\int_a^b \sin\theta(t) dt = 0 
$$

The goal is to prove $\exists t_0 \in [a,b] \ s.t. v(t_0)=(1,0)$.(Under the last formalism it is to prove $\exists t_0 \in [a,b] \ s.t. \theta(t_0) = 2\pi n $ for some $  n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Now how can I prove this?
Also since I have no knowledge about getting information of solution of this type of differential/integral equation, any comment on how/where I can learn about this type of problem would be helpful.

EDIT : I noticed that I need to assume that trajectory is not self-intersecting, that is, $r(t)$ is need to be one-to-one. Otherwise there is an obvious counterexample:[[image: counterexample in the case where <span class=]$r(t)$ is not one-to-one" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tu6ZZ.png)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the extended mean value theorem,
$$
\frac{y(b)-y(a)}{x(b)-x(a)}=\frac{y'(c)}{x'(c)},
$$
which encodes exactly your claim. To avoid the possible division-by-zero in the denominator, use
$$
h(t)=\det\pmatrix{1&1&1\\x(a)&x(b)&x(t)\\y(a)&y(b)&y(t)}
$$
and use the theorem of Rolle: $h(a)=h(b)=0\implies h'(c)=0$ where
$$
h'(c)
=\det\pmatrix{1&1&0\\x(a)&x(b)&x'(c)\\y(a)&y(b)&y'(c)}
=\det\pmatrix{x(b)-x(a)&x'(c)\\y(b)-y(a)&y'(c)}
$$
which also encodes that the tangent at $t=c$ is parallel to $B-A$.

Comment: Thanks! But what I want to prove is there is a moment that tangent vector is pointing "same direction" as $B-A$, not just parallel. Your answer only prove the parallelness(it can be pointing opposite).  Anyway I appreciate your answer cause it really open my eyes about extended mean value theorem.